# Client server program - how to communicate over internet

Tags: vb.net, network-programming, client-server

Right now I have a client-server program that works over LAN. I have managed to ensure that traffic sent to my server gets past the firewall of my company. However, problems occur when the client is communicating from within a LAN - how can I make sure that traffic gets past the firewall/router of the client and to the machine?

Once the client has sent a packet of data the server analyzes this and is meant to send a response; however the server program seems to freeze after the following lines

```
Dim ip As String = (IPAddress.Parse(CType(ClientToManage.Client.RemoteEndPoint, IPEndPoint).Address.ToString())).ToString SendResponse = New TcpClient(ip, 8000)
```

Comment: The firewall is probably blocking outgoing traffic on port 8000?

Answer (score 0):

Possible issues are:
- The server's firewall is blocking outgoing TCP traffic at port 8000.
- The client's firewall is blocking incoming TCP traffic at port 8000.

Adjusting your client's and/or server's firewall settings to allow incoming, respectively outgoing TCP traffic at port 8000 might fix the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I can connect with the server - the difficulty stems from trying to 'reply' to the client. Once the client has sent a packet of data the server analyzes this and is meant to send a response; however the server program seems to freeze after the following lines  Dim ip As String = (IPAddress.Parse(CType(ClientToManage.Client.RemoteEndPoint, IPEndPoint).Address.ToString())).ToString                           SendResponse = New TcpClient(ip, 8000)

Comment: You should probably check if your firewall settings allow incoming tcp traffic at port 8000.